# Selecting DropDownList item alway returns first item

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I seem to be having some trouble with a DropDownList. I have a button that should normaly get the text from the selected DropDownList and compare it in my code on button click. The problem is that the DropDownList returns the first item every time. Here is my code:

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="SubcategoryList" runat="server" 
                DataSourceID="SubCategoryDataSource" DataTextField="SubCategoryName" 
                DataValueField="CategoryId">
  </asp:DropDownList>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SubCategoryDataSource" runat="server" 
                ConnectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\ASPNETDB.MDF;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True" 
                ProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient" 

                SelectCommand="SELECT [SubCategoryName], [CategoryId] FROM [forum_subcategories] WHERE ([CategoryId] = @CategoryId)">
                <SelectParameters>
                    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="CategoryListSelect" Name="CategoryId" 
                        PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
                </SelectParameters>
            </asp:SqlDataSource>

string item = SubcategoryList.SelectedItem.Text;
```

Every time I press my button instead of item getting the value of the item I selected, I get the value of the first Item.

What am I doing wrong here?

**Code for button click**

```
protected void Button9_Click( object sender , EventArgs e ) {
        try
        {
            Label4.Visible = true;
            Label4.Text = "Subcategory deleted";

            string itemSelected = SubcategoryList.SelectedItem.Text;
            DataAccess.insertDeleteCategory(itemSelected , "forum_delete_subcategory");
            addForumData();
        }catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Label4.Text = ex.Message;
        }

}
```

Comment: Haven't done any ASP.NET in ages, but you aren't repopulating the dropdownlist when the button is clicked? You should only populate it when Page.IsPostBack is false, which is when the page is 1st displayed.

Comment: @trydis he uses a datasource

Comment: where is the code for the button_Click?

Comment: I just posted  the code for button click

Comment: I found this on stack. I think it will work for you. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3609712/bound-drop-down-list-changes-to-first-item-in-list

Comment: @ChrisBuckler Yes,but won't that bind the data again when he clicks the button?

Comment: Did you bind category dropdown to sqldatasource as well and does it have "autopostback" true.

Comment: I tried and it works, cross check if you binding/setting these dropdowns in page_load or post back events or may be in javascript.

Comment: (!Page.IsPostBack) on your databind